# Why do we ensure that this function is positive?

Tags: definite-integrals, positive-definite, multiple-integral, jacobian, change-of-variable

My question concerns a detail in the transformation of integrals. In one dimension, given the $$\int_a^bF(x)\mathrm d x,$$ we may perform the substitution $x=f(t)$ under appropriate conditions, which changes the parameters of the integral, so that it now appears as $$\int_A^BG(t)\color{red}{f'(t)}\mathrm d t.$$

However, when we go to higher dimensional domains, and we wish to perform analogous transformations, the new form of the integral involves, in place of $f'(t)$ above, an expression involving the partials of the substitution. For example, in two dimensions, if we wish to perform a change of the parameters of the $$\iint_R F(x,y)\mathrm d A,$$ we may perform $x=f(u,v),y=g(u,v)$ to get $$\iint_S G(u,v)\color{green}{(x_uy_v-x_vy_u)}\mathrm d A.$$ That's what we should *get,* but we instead *use* the absolute value of the expression in green (if it doesn't vanish.) My question is this: *Why is it that we must ensure that this expression (usually put in determinant form and called a jacobian) is positive, especially as we usually just use its one-dimensional analogue without bothering about its sign?*

Thank you.

Comment: I think it is about the domain of $(u,v)$. Consider the 1-dimension case again: for example, when calculating $\int_0^1 (1-x)\,dx$, we can make substitution $t=1-x$ and then we convert it to $\int_1^0 t(-1)\,dt=\int_0^1 t\,dt=\int_0^1t\cdot |-1|\,dt$. So we actually take the absolute value of derivative, in order to make sure the integral domain is $0\to 1$, which has a positive direction.

Comment: @FengShao But the example you gave only seems to work because the intervals $[a,b]$ and $[A,B]$ coincide in all but orientation, or can you make your argument general? Do we indeed always take the absolute value of $f'(t)$?

Comment: I think, generally, if we want $[A,B]$ to be positive direction, we should take the absolute value of $f’(t)$.

Comment: There is really no difference. The sign of the Jacobian indicates whether the transformation is orientation-preserving: in 1 dimension, if the transformation is orientation reversing, "switching the limits" is just a way of multiplying by $-1$ but really has no intrinsic significance. In higher dimensions, a negative Jacobian indicates that the normal vector to the hypersurface has been reversed. There is really no problem unless $J$ changes sign on the region of integration....(continued below)...

Comment: .... Then, you run into technical problems. The best context for this I think is differential geometry, where these ideas are treated rigorously.

Comment: @FengShao I don't see why you think so in general. How doesn't this change the integral? In the example you gave, we're not really changing the integral because we used $[B,A]$ instead of $[A,B].$ So we only hid the negativity of the Jacobian, we did not remove it, as we usually do in higher dimensions.

Comment: @Matematleta You say it has no significance? But isn't $1,$ say, different from $-1?$ So that an integral multiplied by $-1$ is different (unless when the integral vanishes)?

Comment: @Allawonder I mean once you choose an orientation, you can define the integral accordingly and as long as $J$ does not change sign on the region over which you integrate, the sign itself does not matter.

Comment: @Matematleta I'm not sure I understand that. So consider the $\int_0^1 (1-x)\,\mathrm d x$, whose value is $1/2.$ Now let's make the substitution $t=1-x$ and then convert it to $\int_1^0 t(-1)\,\mathrm d t.$ If we now take the jacobian to be positive (as we usually do in higher dimensions), the integral becomes $\int_1^0 t\,\mathrm d t,$ which is $-1/2,$ not $1/2.$ Are you saying that if we *fix* the orientation of all intervals in the direction $+x,$ then we'd always get the correct value if we always take the jacobian to be positive (or, perversely negative)?